# OpenTelemetry Dotnet Tracing for all functions

Tags: open-telemetry

I tried looking through the documentation, but could not find an answer.

I have an several Apis. I wish to trace every single function that they go through. I currently have
builder.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
builder.addAspNetCoreInstrumentation();

but those do not provide that level of details. Can someone point me in the right direction?